# How to dynamically instantiate array of classes based on their class type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, reflection, dependency-injection, factory, strategy-pattern

I implemented a strategy pattern as follow

```
interface IRule {
  isMatch(n: number): boolean;
}

class Rule1 implements IRule {
  isMatch(n: number) {
    return n === 7;
  }
}

class Rule2 implements IRule {
  isMatch(n: number) {
    return n % 2 === 0;
  }
}

class Factory {
  readonly rules: IRule[];

  constructor() {
    this.rules = [new Rule1(), new Rule2()];
  }

  public of(n: number) {
    return this.rules.find(r => r.isMatch(n));
  }
}

const found = new Factory().of(7);
```

**Question:**
Is there a way in TypeScript to create `Factory.Rules` dynamically based on the class type `IRule`?

In C# this could be done as follow:

```cs
var ruleTypeInterface = typeof(IRule);
var rulesType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                        .GetTypes()
                        .Where(t => ruleTypeInterface.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass);
this.rules = rulesType.Select(rt => Activator.CreateInstance(rt) as IRule).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but there are a few syntactical mistakes.

```
class Rule1: IRule {
  isMatch(in: number) {
    return number === 7;
  }
}
```

When you have a `class` that implements an `interface` you write `class Rule1 implements IRule` rather than `class Rule1: IRule`.

`in` is the variable name in your `isMatch` method and `number` is the type, but you are using `number` as if it were the variable name.  `in` is also a reserved word, so let's use `n` instead.

Your `Factory` has the same `in` reserved word issue.  It also has an error `A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword`.  Perhaps you wanted to make it `readonly`?

```
interface IRule {
  isMatch(n: number): boolean;
}

class Rule1 implements IRule {
  isMatch(n: number) {
    return n === 7;
  }
}

class Rule2 implements IRule {
  isMatch(n: number) {
    return n % 2 === 0;
  }
}

class Factory {
  readonly rules: IRule[];

  constructor() {
    this.rules = [new Rule1(), new Rule2()];
  }

  public of(n: number) {
    return this.rules.find(r => r.isMatch(n));
  }
}

const found = new Factory().of(7);
```

This all works now.  The inferred type of `found` is `IRule | undefined` since we do not know (based just on the types) whether `of` will find a match or not.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/KN7Rrw)

Comment: I think the question was really how to use runtime introspection/reflection (like in c#) to auto-populate the `Factory.rules` array. E.g. find all classes implementing `IRule` and populate the array without needing to put them in code. Of course this is not possible in TS as there is no reflection, possibly something like it could be done with experimental decorators but I think it would be a Courageous Decision.

Comment: @Ravenscar Reading it again I think you’re right.  I’m not a C# user so didn’t occur to me that they were trying to find the classes automatically since that’s not a thing you can do in Typescript.

Comment: They could definitely do some sort of type guard check to see which classes are IRules and use those, but all of the possible classes would have to be stored somewhere.